# add into array object change same value java

Tags: java, arrays, collections

After adding userdetails to arr array, all the elements change into same value. Please explain how to do it.

@Autowired
UserDto userDto;

```
public ArrayList getAllUsers()  throws commonException  {
        ArrayList<UserDto> arr = new ArrayList<>(); 
        Iterable<User> user = userRepository.findAll();
        for(User userDetails: user){
             userDto.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
              userDto.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
              userDto.setPassword(userDetails.getPassword());
              arr.add(userDto);
        }



        return arr;
```

Comment: When you add an object to an array or a collection, only a *reference* to the object is added, not a copy of the object. So the references always refer to the *current* content of that object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be incomplete, because you never actually declare the variable `userDto` nor is it initialized.  However, I suspect that the solution to your problem would be to make sure that you initialize a new `UserDto` POJO for *each* iteration of the loop.  Something like this:

```
for (User userDetails: user) {
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();     // CRITICAL
    userDto.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    userDto.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
    userDto.setPassword(userDetails.getPassword());

    arr.add(userDto);
}
```

The reason you end up with multiple copies of the same user currently is that you were reusing the same `UserDto` object, merely changing its values during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new object every time so add this in the loop.

```
UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate UserDto first :

```
for(User userDetails: user){

    //You need to add this
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();

    userDto.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    userDto.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
    userDto.setPassword(userDetails.getPassword());

    arr.add(userDto);
}
```